# Need to make portable snapshot of hard drives, best tool for this?

Tags: backup, image

(redid this question from the ground up)

I need to make portable snapshot images of some hard drives.  The images would be stored on some sort of external media.

My goal is disaster recovery, so this solution would be in order to quickly put an image back onto a fresh drive in order to get a machine back up.

Can you please recommend a tool for this?

(Note that I don't think I need to simply mirror partitions- this does not seem portable to me, as with Disk Copy, or Live CD)

Thanks,

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. You can not create an ISO image of a hard drive. Are you asking how to make an ISO image containing a filesystem populated with files from a hard drive?

Comment: What OS is installed on these drives? And what filesystems are being used?

Comment: Hmm. If it's Windows, you should already _have_ such an image, from which you're deploying the OS in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) -- you're asking for us to give you a list of tools, and that list will become out of date pretty quickly.  There are a number of commercial tools (Ghost used to be very popular) that do this, but you'll have to Google around and evaluate them against your specific needs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Windows computers, then I suggest a linux live CD that contains [ntfsclone](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsclone). This is probably the fastest, most space efficient way to create an image of an NTFS drive.